# Read one-line text file, split to array

Tags: java, arrays, file, text, split

I'm reading a long line of info from a text file that looks exactly like this:

`Sebastien 5000\\Loic 5000\\Shubhashisshh 5000\\Thibaullt 5000\\Caroo 5000\\Blabla 5000\\Okayyy 5000\\SebCed 5000\\abusee 5000\\omg 5000\\`

It's supposed to be high scores with the names of users. When I print out the line, it looks exactly like it should, but when I print out the array after using `split("\\\\")`, it looks like this:

`[Sebastien 5000, , Loic 5000, , Shubhashisshh 5000, , Thibaullt 5000, , Caroo 5000, , Blabla 5000, , Okayyy 5000, , SebCed 5000, , abusee 5000, , omg 5000]`

The problem is that `Array[0]` is fine but `Array[1]` is empty, as are `Array[3]`, `Array[5]`, etc.

Here is my code. What's wrong with it?

```
            BufferedReader in = null;
    try {
        in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    String line = null;
    try {
        line = in.readLine();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("LINE = "+line);

    String[] scores = line.split("\\\\");

    System.out.println("Mode = "+mode+Arrays.toString(scores));
```

Comment: Are you using `line.split("\\\\");` or is that a typo?  I think you need `line.split("\\\");`

Comment: @NickD it takes a regex, so you need `"\\\\"` which first becomes a literal string ``\\`` and then a regex for a literal ``\``. `"\\\"` doesn't compile because it's unterminated string literal.

Comment: It's not a typo, because you have to escape the \ once for a special char and a second time because it's a string if i want to split \\ i have to use \\\\ don't I?

Comment: Your code is working fine for me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's because `"\\\\"` is being parsed as `\\` and the [split method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) uses a regular expression, so `\\` is becoming `\`, then `Sebastien 5000\\Loic 5000` will result in `[Sebastien 5000,,Loic 5000]`

Do this instead: `"\\\\\\\\"`

Comment: Thanks a lot : ) I would never have found that myself :p

Answer (score 3):

Just for fun, aside José Roberto solution, you can also use some alternative expressions (and lots others):

Two consecutive backslashes (same that in José's, but using a quantifier):

```
String[] scores = line.split("\\\\{2}");
```

Two consecutive Non-Word Characters:

```
String[] scores = line.split("\\W{2}");
```

Two consecutive punctuation chars:

```
String[] scores = line.split("\\p{Punct}{2}");
```

All of them produce the required output.

For more info on Regular expressions in Java:

- [Class Pattern Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)
- [Java tutorial on Regular Expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/)

Answer (score 0):

I would have gone one further than Nick:

`line.split("\\\");`

This view assumes that you are trying to split the line at each point where the double back-slash appears - it seems like your code is splitting at every alternate double-slash, which would explain the double commas between each name; therefore, between each split part (i.e. each of the sections between the commas, there are two entries instead of one, so that one entry is simply a comma alone).  See if this works - Good Luck!!

M.

Comment: "\\" in java is single slash actually, and for regexp this is an escape character, so "\\\\" means single slash in regexp